# How to add domain to Google Cloud Storage object ACL at creation?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, acl, google-cloud-storage

In my Java based app-engine project, i allow users to upload files to google cloud store (this works), but i can't seem to add a specific domain to the access list, so that only people from within my company can access my files. How do i do this?

i tried using:

```
    GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());
    GcsFilename gcsFileName = new GcsFilename("my-bucket", user_uploaded_file_name);
    Builder fileOptionsBuilder = new GcsFileOptions.Builder();
    fileOptionsBuilder.mimeType(mimeType);
    fileOptionsBuilder.acl("authenticated-read"); // how do i modify this list?
    GcsFileOptions fileOptions = fileOptionsBuilder.build();
    GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(gcsFileName, fileOptions);
```

and this `authenticated-read` just makes the file public (not what i want). i want to add everyone from the organization "@mycompany.com" to the access list. do i do this through code? or do i do this using the google cloud console?

I will be providing people the links to files they upload via this url:

`String url = https://console.developers.google.com/m/cloudstorage/b/" + "my-bucket" + "/o/" + user_uploaded_file_name;`

Answer (score 1):

Oh wow. this guy was really helpful and had a Java version:

[Changing ACL for Google Cloud Storage from Appengine (JAVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616007/changing-acl-for-google-cloud-storage-from-appengine-java)

this totally worked for me!